# MATLAB: Plot google map with nice m_map borders / projections

Tags: matlab, plot, mmap

I would like to create a google satellite image of an area using the function plot_google_map but with a nice border or on a certain map projections using m_map functions. Anyone know how to do this?

https://www.eoas.ubc.ca/~rich/map.html#7._Lambert_Conformal_Projection_with_Med

some basic code, it's more the problem of combining the two functions:

```
m_grid('linestyle','none','tickdir','out','linewidth',3); %m_map projection
hold on
plot_google_map('maptype','satellite','showlabels','scale') % google map satellite
ylim([38 46]); % latitude
xlim([4 12]); % longitude
```

I tried it the other way, plot_google_map first and then m_grid but doesn't work either. Tried different projections too.

Ideally it would be nice to have the satellite image within the border, and if this example projections is too difficult, a straight forward square would be fine.

Comment: "I've tried to do it but with no luck.." We folks that help in stackoverflow get very nervous when people say this. We **dont want to know** if you tried, we **want to see** what you tried.

Comment: yes sorry about that, added some basic code, which I have been altering in different ways to see if it works (i.e. changing projections, sequence of commands, plot_google_map settings).

Comment: anyone know how to solve this??

Comment: Read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054/329117), you can also make your question look attractive by providing small and nice pics / plots. I am not a [tag:matlab] expert but tried to read the question and couldn't understand much why you provided that link (lacks a brief note?).